# How to execute Postgresql Query

Tags: postgresql-9.5

How to group by name and get the average of Ganesh and Suresh marks

```
I have a PSQL table like below
 Name             Marks
Ganesh            80
Ganesh            90
Ganesh            70
Suresh            60
Suresh            70
Suresh            75
```

I am expecting output like below:

```
Name        Marks
Ganesh      240
Suresh      205
```

I need an Postgresql query to get get the above output

Comment: Does `SELECT Name, AVG(Marks) from table1 GROUP BY Name;` not work?